# neo4j - returning the first row, without grouping

Tags: neo4j, group-by, row, limit

I am trying to do the following with neo4j.
We have nodes that have a set of attributes. One of these attributes is a date.

I am looking to have these attributes returned, but only picking up the occurrence with the latest date.

In SQL, my query would have looked like this:

```
select commonKey, attr1, attr2, dateAttr
from ( 
   select commonKey, attr1, attr2, dateAttr, 
   row_number(
         partition by commonKey 
         order by commonKey ASC, dateAttr DESC
     ) rn
from tab 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in Cypher?
There is a collect(dateAttr)[1], but this will group by all attributes I need to have returned (commonKey, attr1, attr2), whereas I only care to "group" by commonKey, but return others - from the first row within the group.

Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

--Alex

Comment: Can you provide the Cypher you've tried so far?

Comment: something like this:

     match (p)
         xxx
     ORDER BY  
         commonKey
         ,dateAttr DESC

     WITH 
         commonKey
         ,attr1
         ,attr2
         ,collect(dateAttr)[1] as TDate
     RETURN 
          commonKey
         ,attr1
         ,attr2
         ,TDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're projecting the properties too soon. It would probably work better to order the nodes by the date, then either collect() grouping by the date and take the first:

```
MATCH (n:MyNode) 
WHERE ...
WITH n, n.dateAttr as dateAttr
ORDER BY dateAttr DESC 
WITH dateAttr, collect(n)[0] as n
RETURN n.commonKey, n.attr1, n.attr2, dateAttr as TDate
```

Alternately you can use APOC Procedures, which has [aggregation functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_aggregation_functions) for this kind of case:

```
MATCH (n:MyNode) 
WHERE ...
WITH n, n.dateAttr as dateAttr
ORDER BY dateAttr DESC 
WITH dateAttr, apoc.agg.first(n) as n
RETURN n.commonKey, n.attr1, n.attr2, dateAttr as TDate
```